# Multiple Nav update Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2007

Created a header and footer nav. The header nav contains 1 UL and the footer nav contains 5 UL. I want the li:first child of each UL in the footer nav to match up with the header nav. The footer nav has the same main li as the header nav but contain sub li within them Can someone please help me out?

I created a jsFiddle of my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/WkZuv/41/

```
$(".Nav > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");
    }
});

$(".footer > li:first-child").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(".Nav > li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("menuClicked");     

         $(".footer > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");  
    }
});

.menuHover{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#fff;
}
.menuClicked{
    background-color:yellow;
    color:#666;
}

.footerTitle{
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
}

<h1>Header NAV</h1>
<ul class="Nav">
    <li class ="menuClicked"> List 1 </li> 
    <li>List 2 </li>
    <li> List 3 </li>
    <li> List 4 </li>
    <li> List 5</li>
</ul>

<hr />

<h1>FOOTER NAV</h1>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 1 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 2 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 3 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 4 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 5 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note: Use `.on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/), `.live()` is depreciated.

Comment: @dom My client is using jquery 1.5

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for. Try something like this:

```
$(".Nav > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
        $(".footer > li:first-child").eq($(this).index()).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
        $(".footer > li:first-child").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");
        $(".footer > li:first-child").removeClass("menuClicked").eq($(this).index()).addClass("menuClicked");
    }
});

$(".footer > li:first-child").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
        $(".Nav>li").eq($(".footer").index($(this).parent("ul"))).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
        $(".Nav>li").eq($(".footer").index($(this).parent("ul"))).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(".footer > li:first-child").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");
        $(".Nav>li").eq($(".footer").index($(this).parent("ul"))).addClass("menuClicked");
    }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/WkZuv/65/

Comment: the 'ul' part is unnecessary: you can do this instead
`$(".footer").index($(this).parent())`

Comment: Yeah I know, it's more to explain what's going on, in case he isn't too familiar with jQuery.

Comment: well your answer should be marked as correct.. you got my vote up though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the following statement.

```
$(".Nav > li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("menuClicked");
```

$(this).index() is always returning zero. Try adjusting your css selector to match the set of ul.footer elements to get the correct index. You will have to make some other modifications though.